# Date comparison in varchar format

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
IF('08/30/2015'>'08/29/2016')
SELECT '1'
ELSE
SELECT '0'
```

This SQL statement returns 1 because it is comparing only month and day and ignoring the year.  I know I am comparing two varchar values - not the dates - but I want to know what logic SQL follows for this comparison?

Can anybody help me please?   This same scenario gave me an issue in a project, and I fixed that by casting to date.  However, I want to know the logic behind this.  I searched it but didn't find a proper explanation.

Comment: It compares them as strings, naturally. It compares them character by character, the first that differs is 3 vs. 2, 3 is greater than 2, hence the result is 1.

Answer (score 4):

Your values are not dates.  They are strings.  You could do:

```
IF (convert(date, '08/30/2015') > convert(date, '08/29/2016'))
    SELECT '1'
ELSE
    SELECT '0';
```

(Note:  Whether or not this works may depend on your internationalization settings for the date format.  I assume that is set up to understand MDY format.)

But why bother?  Just use ISO standard date formats (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
IF ('2015-08-30' > '2015-08-29')
    SELECT '1'
ELSE
    SELECT '0';
```

These don't need a conversion because the strings compare correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's comparing two character strings, so even though a human would look at these and think of dates, SQL just sees that one character string is greater than another.  If you take out the slashes and just put the numbers out there, it might make more sense: `08302015 > 08292016`.

Comment: This won't work because it will sort on the month and day before the year (i.e. in your example, 2015 is not really greater than 2016, is it?)

Comment: @Ben I'm not suggesting this as a calculation, but rather answering his question about how the logic is working when comparing the values presented.  He already stated that he got the date to resolve correctly by casting, and the question was why the strings calculated the way they did.  Taking the the slashes out might make that clearer to a human, which was what I was attempting to communicate.  Maybe you should read the question more carefully.

Comment: Oops. My bad. SO won't allow me to remove my downvote. Sorry about that.

Comment: No worries.  It happens :)